# how to create a table x with similar data as y and also declaring few more new columns in oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle

i want to create a table similar to other table and also want to declare few more new columns at same time.

I tried  like

```
create table emp2 as ((select * from emp)),age varchar2(3))
```

But its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add additional columns in your CTAS (Create Table As Select), you'll have to provide data for them. If you want to leave the column empty, you can use `CAST(null as <your datatype>)`:

```
create table dual_copy as 
select 
  d.*, 
  cast(null as varchar2(3)) as age 
from dual d;
```

A word of advice, though: Explicitly storing the age of people is never a good idea (people tend to get older over time :-) ). Just store the birth date and compute the age on-the-fly. Alternatively (if you're running 11g or later), you could add a virtual column for the age.

And if you insist on explicitly storing the age, you should at least use a numeric datatype instead of a `varchar2`.

Comment: Hi Frank,thankful for your response..Its working..how to  impose constraints  or to give default values on new columns..

Comment: @user3772434 AFAIK, you can't. But you should ask this as a different question on SO.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the `age` column in another statement:

```
CREATE TABLE emp2 AS SELECT * FROM emp;

ALTER TABLE emp2 ADD age VARCHAR2(32);
```

Comment: hi mureinik,thanks for your response..I want  to make it in single statement.